# How to start a service using init.d in raspberry pi running raspbian?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have Raspbian installed on my raspberry pi. I found some guides that should allow me to auto-start scripts on startup. But it is not working.

**I ran update-rc.d (not sure of the right spelling) and I checked and it created various entries in /etc/rcx.d**. These entries start in either with the letter K or S.

I can run the script fine manually using "sudo service myscripthere start" (or a stop/restart). "mybinary" is located in /usr/local/bin.

Any ideas on what could be wrong? thanks

---

This is the contents of the script.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myscript
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
start)   echo -n "Start services"
   /usr/local/bin/mybinary -start
   ;;
stop)   echo -n "Stop services"
   /usr/local/bin/mybinary -stop
   ;;
restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
        ;;
*)   echo "Usage: $0 start|stop|restart"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: I think your scripts are not getting called. Makesure it gets invoked from /etc/rcX.d/Syourscript, here X is the runlevel (could be 2,3,4,5 - which runlevel you want your script to be invoked), "S" stands it's active, if you use "K" yourscript won't be invoked and S should be followed by two digits. Have you done all of this? Take sample from /etc/rcX.d/ directory. See what happens.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi /etc $ find . -name S*nzbget*
./rc2.d/S01nzbget-daemon
./rc4.d/S01nzbget-daemon
./rc5.d/S01nzbget-daemon
./rc3.d/S01nzbget-daemon